# I want to sort integers within the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a program that receives information of restaurant reservations, but I want to sort the reservations chronologically by time.

The function takes a `-txt.file` as an argument and the content of the file follows this structure - 
`"name", "time", "status"` (`"status"` is `CONFIRMED` or `CANCELLED`). It's only supposed to display the `CONFIRMED` reservations and sort them by `"time"`. So far, I've been able to display the reservations, but I just don't know how to sort them.

```
def show_reservations(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        content = file.readlines()

    for reservation in content:
        dictionary = {}
        if ", CONFIRMED" in reservation:
            dictionary.setdefault(reservation[:-12], "CONFIRMED")
            empty_list = []
            for k, v in dictionary.items():
                print(k)


print(show_reservations(blabla.txt))
```

Arbitrary content of -txt.file:

```
MARTIN, 19, CONFIRMED
JULIE, 18, CONFIRMED
METTE, 17, CANCELLED
```

Desired output:

```
JULIE, 18
MARTIN, 19
```

Comment: Sorry, we can only accept code *as text*, not as images. Not everyone can read images (they could be blocked at their location, or they use a screenreader, or are a search engine that would like to index the source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works if you are storing each reservation as a dictionary with two key-value pairs, and storing them into a list.

sorted() allows you to sort the list of reservations. You can then choose the sorting factor by specifying it using lambda. :)

```
def show_reservations(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        content = file.readlines()

    # list to store confirmed reservations
    confirmed_list = []

    for reservation in content:
        # dict to be re-used to parse each reservation
        r = {}
        if ", CONFIRMED" in reservation:
            # splits each line to a list          e.g. ["JULIE", "16", "CONFIRMED"]
            reserv = reservation.split(",")
            # gets first element which is the name of customer and stores in dict
            # strip is to remove any leading/trailing whitespace
            r['name'] = reserv[0].strip()
            # gets second element which is the time of reservation and stores in dict
            r['time'] = reserv[1].strip()
            # appends dict to list
            confirmed_list.append(r)

    # sorts the list of confirmed reservations by time using lambda
    confirmed_list_s = sorted(confirmed_list, key=lambda k: k['time'])

    for r in confirmed_list_s:
        # prints out each reservation in sorted list
        row = ", ".join(val for key, val in r.items())
        print(row)

show_reservations("blabla.txt")
```

Output:

```
JO, 16
JULIE, 18
MARTIN, 19
CHARLIE, 20
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry, which part of it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens well, besides the complex lambda, i added comments for your understanding, if you have difficulties understanding how loops and dicts work :)

Comment: This is golden. I get it now. Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful. I hope that my post was easy to interpret, since this is my first time posting on Stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisBanniq It's my first time too, glad I could help :)